# postgresql -- Curval not working, using PHP PDO

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

So I'm trying to run some SQL here through PHP's PDO (which I don't believe should be the problem) like such:

```
INSERT INTO example (
    d_id,
    s_id
) 
    VALUES (
    currval('d_id_seq'),
    currval('s_id_seq')
);
```

I have two sequences called `d_id_seq` and `s_id_sec` (lets pretend I have a table named `d` and a table named `s`, and this sequence is a column called ID and `serial` type).

Now, obviously I'm doing this wrong, as I get an error about the sequence not being used in this session:

> Object not in prerequisite state: 7 ERROR:  currval of sequence "d_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session

So, how should I write this?

Comment: Typically in an insert you use NEXTVAL,  and you use CURVAL to read the value inserted. See the docs. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-sequence.html

Comment: I'm inserting values that are in *other* tables, not this one.

Comment: Then you should either read that values from the tables themselves (if you have their keys), or make sure that they have been inserted in those tables "recently" - i.e., during this session (connection). BTW, this is not related to PHP PDO at all, as you rightly suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means you did not "use" the sequence in this session (postgres connection). For instance you did not do any INSERTs on the table d.

Perhaps you have a bug in your code and reconnect to postgres after each query ?

A more convenient way to do it is to use INSERT RETURNING on your INSERTs. Then you get the ids.

Answer (score 2):

Problem can be solved via the following command:

```
SELECT last_value FROM d_id_seq;
```

Note that I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.9, I do not know about other or older versions.

Answer (score 1):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html):

> `currval`
>   Return the value most recently obtained by nextval for this sequence in the current session. (An error is reported if nextval has never been called for this sequence in this session.) Because this is returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer whether or not other sessions have executed nextval since the current session did.

You use `currval` to get the *last* value that was pulled out of the sequence *in the current session*. The usual pattern is to do an INSERT that uses a sequence and then you call `currval` to figure out what value the INSERT used. If you haven't called `nextval` with the sequence in question in the current session then there is nothing for `currval` to return.

Maybe you're actually looking for `select max(id) from d` and `select max(id) from s`:

```
INSERT INTO example (d_id, s_id)
SELECT MAX(d.id), MAX(s.id)
FROM d, s;
```

Or maybe you need to wrap your `d` and `s` inserts in a stored procedure that takes care of inserting in all three tables at once.